# Sails.js Data undefined

Tags: javascript, sails.js, ejs

I'm trying to create function named Edit function and update function to update items in the database bying using sails.js but its said Length it can't read property of undefined. I'm kinda stuck here, please help.

[This is a picture of Edit and Update functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwP2w.png)

[This is an error result that I got when I click on Edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6VNu.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Edit Item | Make4You</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 
 <body>
 
 <h1 class="">Edit Item</h1>
 <form method="post" action="/item/update?id=<%= items.id %>"> 
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="title">Title</label>
   <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="<%= items.title %>">
   <label for="category_id">Category</label>
   <select name="category_id">
   <% for (var j=0; j<categories.length; j++){ %>
   <option value="<% if(items[i].category_id == categories[j].id){ %>"><%= categories[j].name %></option>
   <% } %>
   <% } %>
   </select>
   <label for="description">Description</label>
   <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" value="<%= items.description %>">
   <label for="width">Width</label>
   <input type="text" name="width" class="form-control" value="<%= items.width %>">
   <label for="height">Height</label>
   <input type="text" name="height" class="form-control" value="<%= items.height %>">
   <label for="price">Price</label>
   <input type="price" name="price" class="form-control" value="<%= items.price %>">

  </div>

  
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your edit method, it looks like you are trying to fetch both an `Item` and a `Category` using the same id (`req.param('id')`)... you probably mean to either pass in two different ids, or use a category id attached to the fetched `Item` or something...

Also, you have a little confusion between `find` and `findOne`. `find` will always return an array of results, possibly empty. `findOne` will return a single object if found, or `undefined` if not:

```
Category.find({id: category_id}).exec(function(err, results) {
    // results is an array, possibly empty
});

Category.findOne({id: category_id}).exec(function(err, results) {
    // results is either a model or undefined
});
```

From the error returned from your view, it looks like maybe you want the array. And remember that checking for empty results (`undefined` or a zero-length array) is a distict check from looking at the `err` parameter - empty results are not an error.

Comment: so if I change Category.find().exec(finction(err, result){} it will work?

Comment: @MaxKasem it will stop giving you the length error. However, I don't know what your `Categories` are, or which ones you are looking for, so "it will work" depends on what you intend. Make sure you read the first part as well, because I'm pretty sure you didn't mean to use the same id for your Item and your Category.

Comment: yes I didn't know that before. Thank you so much!! Now, its worked!